# Get the executing file's path from an installed package?

Tags: python

If one installs a python package using setuptools, then executes a method in that package from a standard python script, is it possible to get the file path of the calling/executing file?

For instance, the file I'm executing is `/usr/foo/bar.py`, which looks like this:

```
import baz
baz.get_current_path()
# should print /usr/foo/bar.py
```

and the package `baz` has been installed using setuptools and is located in that magical place all python packages are installed when they've been good little packages.

Both `__file__` and `import inspect; inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_filename` return the path of the package'd file.

Is this possible?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.  Do you just want `sys.argv[0]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inspect.getouterframes()` or `inspect.stack()`, then get the filename from the calling frame.

Comment: `import inspect; inspect.stack()[-1][0].f_code.co_filename` did the trick. Thanks!